# How to get specific part of object when calling touch listener on Corona

Tags: listener, coronasdk

I have a group which presents a character. It contains head, arms and other parts of body. 
I want to set touch Listener to that group so when I touch the head, arms and body will do some movements.
I don't want to set touch listener to head only, but the whole group.
I set name to head, and hope event.other can work(like collision), but it's not.

Do you have any solution?
My code below

```
local touchListener= function( event )
        if (event.phase=="began") then
            local group = event.target
            local head= group[1]
            local arms= group[2]
            local body= group[3]

            if( event.other.name == "head" ) then

            // do something here
            end
        end
return true
end
```

Comment: you want to have different movement on every touch? for example the head has different movement than the arms or all of them is the same?

Comment: I want the program knows exactly where I touched: the head. Because I set listener to the whole group(character), not every element of that group(head,arms...), so it's hard for me to get the part I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first create those spesific parts of the body. And then you should add touch listeners to everyone of them. For example, you have objects named "head", "arms" and "body"

```
head.id = "head"
arms.id = "arms"
body.id = "body"
```

---

```
head:addEventListener( "touch", touchHandler )
arms:addEventListener( "touch", touchHandler )
body:addEventListener( "touch", touchHandler )
```

---

```
-- Touch function here
    local function touchHandler( event )
        if event.phase == "began" then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( event.target )
            event.target.isFocus = true 
        elseif event.target.isFocus then
            if event.phase == "moved" and not ( inBounds( event ) ) then
                display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
                event.target.isFocus = false
            elseif event.phase == "ended" then
                if event.id == "head" then
                  -- Do stuff for head
                elseif event.id == "arms" then
                  -- Do stuff for arms
                elseif event.id == "body" then
                  -- Do stuff for body
                end
                display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
                event.target.isFocus = false
            end
        end
        return true
    end
```

---

```
function inBounds( event )
    local bounds = event.target.contentBounds
    if event.x > bounds.xMin and event.x < bounds.xMax and event.y > bounds.yMin and event.y  < bounds.yMax then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

This code will also look for boundries of an object. For example, if user touchs the screen and then moves his/her finger to outside of the object, the object will no longer be focused.
Cheers ^^